# Indy's TIdMappedPortTCP maximum number of simultaneous connections?

Tags: delphi, indy10

I have created a simple Delphi service application which uses Indy's TIdMappedPortTCP to redirect connection from one port to another port on a remote server.

The application does not process the traffic in any form. It only redirects the traffic to a remote server using DefaultPort, MappedPort and MappedHost properties.

I need to know what is the maximum number of connections it can handle and what are the different factors that would affect the performance such as OS, Architecture(32bit/64bit) ..etc.

My current test shows that TIdMappedPortTCP can handle 1500 connection with over 1500 threads.

I'm expecting that simultaneous connections will increase to 10000 or even 20000.

**## Update 1 ##**

My tests shows that the application uses 50000KB (50MB) for 1000 TCP connections (1000 threads).

**## Update 2 ##**

The application is currently using over 6000 threads (6000 TCP connections) and the memory usage is only 250MB with no performance issues!

Comment: The problem is that a Thread uses quite some resources from the OS. If you want to handle that much simultaneous connections, you will need to change your architecture (and that means moving away from Indy). Take a look/google at [IOCP](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365198(VS.85).aspx). A good library that supports IOCP is [this one](https://bitbucket.org/voipobjects/iocpengine).

Comment: Indy cannot handle that kind of threads not because of the indy itself, it's because of the O.S. as @whosrdaddy mentioned. You'll experience, over 2000 threads, the O.S. will be unable to create new threads because of resource exhaustion. See, if don't intervened a thread's stack size will be 1-MB and 2000 simultaneous threads' memory usage will be 2-GB..

Comment: At the time of writing this comment, the current number of threads are 1020 and the memory usage is 50000KB which is 50MB which I think is fine!

Comment: Isn't it the Heap usage?

Comment: I'm referring to "Working Set" from the Windows task manager process list

Comment: You could decrease stack preallocation. And you should examine memory of your process in better detail.

Comment: Check "Update 2". I hope someone can explain to me what is going on!